# superexponentiation of integers yields integers

Tags: exponentiation, integers, foundations

I recently read Nelson's ['Warnings signs of a potential collapse in the foundations of mathematics'](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/papers/warn.pdf) and one of his three warning signs was the implicit assumption of mathematicians that the exponentiation and super-exponentiation of integers always yields integers.

However, I think that this can be easily shown by induction. Have I missed something here or is Nelson the only mathematician who believes this?

Comment: I haven't found a response to that particular paper, but this may be a useful discussion on one of Nelson's later claims related to peano arithmetic https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/09/the_inconsistency_of_arithmeti.html

Comment: There are ultrafinitists which don't believe in the infinitude of the natural numbers. It stands to believe that there are people who reject the idea of induction being sound. Nelson worked hard to try and find a problem with Peano, his lack of success speaks volumes, in my opinion, on the strength of these axioms.

Comment: I do not understand the problems ultrafinists have with extremely large numbers or to accept that obvious rules apply to arbitary large numbers. Nor can I understand the rejection of the idea of the induction.